# Only show child items in current navigation with Managed Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-navigation

I'm using Managed Metadata Navigation on my SharePoint Online site.
I have configured it to use friendly urls and all nodes points to the same aspx-page (The page lists articles from a document library depending on navigating term).

I want the global(top) navigation to show my root nodes and the current(left/quick) navigation to only show child nodes of the currently selected node not including the currently selected node and it's siblings.

The root nodes in the term set is marked to only be displayed in the global navigation. All child nodes is marked to only be displayed in the current navigation.

When I have these settings the current navigation will not show anything.
If I change the root nodes to be displayed on the current navigation the current navigation shows the currently selected node(with child nodes) and it's siblings.

I have also tried to change the values for ShowStartingNode, StartFromCurrentNode, StartingNodeOffset on the asp:SiteMapDataSource control in the master page but that does not change anything.